# How to tell if MvcBuildViews actually works

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to precompile my Razor views so that any problems are figured out before runtime. I've added the       `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>` into my .csproj file and changed some of my existing views to be invalid (e.g. used non-existent partial names) and there are no build errors when I clean and rebuild the solution.

Does this MvcBuildViews actually do anything and where/how can I test that it's working?